# JavaFX TreeTableView - center displayed values inside column

Tags: java, javafx

[image]

I need to center the values displayed inside columns of a treetableview, how Can i change the position from left to center?

```
final TreeTableColumn<RootMaster, Integer> dataColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Data");
dataColumn.setEditable(false);
dataColumn.setMinWidth(300);
dataColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<RootMaster, Integer>("bu..."));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `cellFactory` on the `TreeTableColumn` (as well as the `cellValueFactory`).

```
dataColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
    TreeTableCell<RootMaster, Integer> cell = new TreeTableCell<RootMaster, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    return cell ;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man for taking the time answer the qustion, much appreciated